# Open ServerSocket on remote machine with java?

Tags: java, serversocket

I've created a simple method in attempts to determine if a socket is open on a remote machine. Here is my code:

```
public static Boolean isPortAvailable( int port, String bindAddr  ) {
    try { 
        System.out.println("IP: " + InetAddress.getByName(bindAddr ));
        ServerSocket srv = new ServerSocket(port, 0, InetAddress.getByName(bindAddr ) );  

        srv.close();  
        srv = null;  
        return true;  

    } catch (IOException e) {  
        return false;  
    }
}
```

Passing it these two args:

```
String bindAddr  = "remotemachinename";
int port = 1719;
```

It continues to tell me the port is not available but if I try netstat -a on the machine I see it's clearly NOT in use.  Am I missing something?

Comment: As both answers are telling you, you have completely misunderstood what that ServerSocket constructor does. You can't use it to open a ServerSocket on a remote machine. How would that even work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to contact a listening (server) socket you should use a `Socket` not a `ServerSocket`.  See the [ServerSocket javadoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/ServerSocket.html), the third parameter of the ServerSocket constructor is a **local** address to **bind** to, not a **remote** address to **connect** to.

Try this:

```
try {
    InetAddress addr = InetAddress.getByName(bindAddr);
    Socket sock = new Socket();
    SocketAddress sockaddr = new InetSocketAddress(addr, port);
    int timeout = 1000;   // wait for 1 second = 1000ms (adapt to your use case)
    sock.connect(sockaddr, timeout);
} catch (UnknownHostException e) {
} catch (SocketTimeoutException e) {
    // nobody's listening or willing to accept our connection...
} catch (IOException e) {
}
```

Comment: That did it...not sure how I missed that. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

What you are missing is ignoring your IOException which is probably telling you, you cannot pretend to be another server.  I suggest you only ignore select expected exceptions

Use a Socket as @fvu suggests and return a `boolean` not a `Boolean`